# Get value of a text box of a pop up menu

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a pop up menu,which has a text box,when I go in a inspect elemnt its like the following,my question is how can get the value of this specific box

```
< input name="DeviceIP" class="k-input k-textbox" type="text" data-bind="value:DeviceIP" >
```

Comment: No code and it doesn't make any sense. `:(`

Comment: @PraveenKumar there is a code

Comment: Yea right. There are answers as well. It has been edited by Dij... `:)`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because a simple search on the internet would have been enough to get an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In jQuery, you can get and set values of inputs via [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/). The following should work

```
$('input[name="DeviceIP"]').val();
```

If you wanna do it in pure javascript, you can do this instead:

```
document.getElementsByName("DeviceIP")[0].value;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can access the element using `getElementsByName` and then use `value` :
`document.getElementsByName("DeviceIP")[0].value`